# set a time each day the code starts and time when the code stops and continues from that point on the next day

Tags: javascript, html

How can I set a time each day the code starts and time when the code stops and continues from that point on the next day?

```js
var timeInterval = 1000; //value in ms you want the code to run

setInterval(function(){
  var frame = document.getElementById('frame');
  var prev = frame.src.match(/.*?=(\d*)/)[1];
  var next = (+prev) + 1;
  frame.src = frame.src.replace(/id=(\d*)/, "id="+next);
  console.log(frame.src);
}, timeInterval);
```

```html
<iframe id='frame' src="https://www.example.com/id=108559" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no">
</iframe>
```

Comment: maybe you should save the latest id generated to the localStorage, next day you can start interval from this id (as I understand in your question).

Answer (score 0):

Use local storage.try something like this:

```
if (!localStorage.getItem("count")) {
  var count = 0;
  localStorage.setItem("count", count);
} else {
  var count = localStorage.getItem("count");
}

var timeInterval = 1000; //value in ms you want the code to run

setInterval(function() {
  console.log(count++);
}, timeInterval);
```